# how to buy proxy servers

Tags: proxy, socks

I need to buy/setup 100 quality socks 5 servers, I am looking for a cheap but quality solution.  Is there such service I can buy somewhere?

Comment: What possible purpose, other than spam relaying, would 100 socks 5 servers serve?

Comment: Cheap but quality? They're as near mutually exclusive as you can get.

Comment: sounds like he wants to watch Hulu :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to buy 100 physical servers to run as proxies?

If so, sounds like a job for Dell weekend specials.

Answer (score 0):

Dell, or if you want another solution I can sell you loads for Dell + 3% and we include this nice shiny bridge! You're going to have to be a little more specific :)